Black Box puzzle: buttons and lights
I am trying to solve a Black Box puzzle from Workroom Productions. It features several buttons and lights. When you press the button(s), some light(s) turn on, while others may turn off. You can consider the buttons as INPUT and the lights as OUTPUT.
There are four buttons as inputs and four lights as outputs. Initially all buttons and lights are off. The arrangement of the buttons as inputs are like this: the first two buttons (button 1 and button 2) are in the first row and other two buttons (button 3 and button 4) in the second row. The output results for different input combinations are as follows:

Diagonal combination of two buttons: Light number 3 turns on when a diagonal combination of two buttons happen, i.e. either button 1 and 4 or button 2 and 3 are pressed.
Individual Combination:  When buttons are pressed individually nothing happens. No light is turned on.
Vertical Combination of two buttons:

When buttons that are in the first column (buttons 1, 3) pressed, nothing happens
similarly nothing happens for the buttons in the second column (buttons 2,4).


Horizontal Combination of two buttons:

Light 2 is turned on if buttons 1 and 2 from the first row are pressed.
Light 4 is turned on if buttons 3 and 4 from the second row are pressed.


Combination of three buttons:

Lights 2 and 3 are turned on under two conditions. Either the combination of buttons 1,2,3 or the combination of buttons 1,2,4 are pressed on.
Similarly for lights 3 and 4, either the combination of buttons 1,3,4 or the combination of buttons 2,3,4 are pressed on.


Combination of all Four buttons: Lights 1 and 4 are turned on when all the buttons (1,2,3,4) are pressed on.

What is the underlying processing logic behind this puzzle?

This was previously asked on Mathematics SE but was closed.

yes But question was not properly answered on  Mathematics SE . Since it was closed due to lacking of proper context and details .

We require proper attribution. Please do not remove the source from your question.

Despite knowing we have an attribution policy, you have now sabotaged this puzzle's attribution three times, including by removing it from the title each time. The first time by removing any acknowledgement of a source. The second and third times by changing the link to either a broken link or a different puzzle. Public revision history. I've raised a moderator flag instead of editing again as I don't want to get into a rollback war, but this is still against the rules.

I've locked this for a little while. I'd like to understand sunflower's reason for the edits bobble is complaining about. Given that the very first version of the question had the correct link in it, it's hard to believe that sunflower is deliberately trying to avoid proper attribution, but I'm not sure what better explanation there is. @sunflower, could you explain what's going on here? Thanks!

Ah, sorry, of course @sunflower can't comment here while the post is locked. But you can either (1) hop over to the PSE chatroom at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair or else (2) wait a few hours until the lock on this question expires and then (not restart the revert-war, please, but) explain things here in comments.

(I will be away from my computer for much of the next day or so, but I promise that I'll see whatever you write...)

The answer is that the lights show

 the product of two 2-bit numbers (formed by the button columns) as a single 4-bit number.

In more detail:

 Each button column is a 2-bit number, with the top button having value 2 and the bottom one value 1, so together a column can have any value from 0 to 3.
 Labelling the buttons like this:
  a     c 
  b     d 
 Buttons a and b represent the first number in binary (2a+b), and c and d together represent the second number (2c+d).

 The lights are a 4-bit binary number, so the lights have values 8, 4, 2, and 1 from left to right and could theoretically display any value from 0 to 15.

 In this puzzle the lights show the product of the two button column numbers, so will actually only show one of the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 9.

 For example, if the top two buttons are pressed, the lights will show $2*2=4=0100_2$, so only the second light will be on. If all the buttons are pressed, it will show $3*3=9$ so the first and last light will be on ($9 = 8+1 = 1001_2$).


I am still confused about the button column value and how they are multiplying . Top button (button 1) has value of  2  ,bottom button (button 4 ) has value of  1 . So what is the value of button 2 and 3 . How is all the buttons(1,2,3,4) pressed  becomes (3*3)=9 . Can you also explain it for diagonal combination

@sunflower What you labelled buttons 1 and 3 are the two buttons in the left column, they form the first number (button 1 contributes value 2 if pressed, button 3 value 1). Similarly, buttons 2 and 4, forming the column of buttons on the right are used to input the second number. So if for example diagonal buttons 1 and 4 are pressed, the left number is 2, the right number is 1, making the product 2, so only the third light is on. If all the buttons are pressed, the left button column is 2+1=3, and the right column is 2+1=3, so the product is 9, or 1001 in binary.

I think I have understood your logic . Puzzle is about multiplication between two numbers . First number and second number are formed by left column buttons and right column buttons respectively. Just to be 100% sure,  Individual and horizontal combinations of buttons don't show any output because the output is zero . Logic behind this is Example if I press button a and c no light will be on because button b and d are off and so multiplication result will be zero . Right button column is zero . Am I right

@Gareth McCaughan  may I know if it is not possible to delete the puzzle ? I posted the puzzle . I understood the puzzle. I wanted to delete it for some unavoidable reasons .  Don't I have the right to delete it as I was the one who posted it? When the deleting option was not working or saying I can't do this ,  I wanted to edit some details in the puzzle so that this question gets deleted . Violation of proper attribution  was not my intention . I was only hoping that this puzzle question gets deleted .

So if the post was not deleted,  I was thinking to give less but accurate details in the edit version .  I wanted to reduce details for this puzzle . only wanted to reduce some lines Wrong or broken Links must have been a careless mistake. @Gareth McCaughan

I still wanted to edit the first line (wanted to remove this particular portion " black box puzzle from workroom production")  and not talking about changing the link . I don't know what was happening , other moderator was always dismissing my edit version . I was not allowed to remove this small detail.  so .Each time it was rolled back to first version .  Why can't I change that ? I still need to do that@Gareth McCaughan .  I am not talking about the link portion .

This question has been revealed to come from a competition.

Well I already mentioned  that this is some kind of fun challenge that happens  in school/coaching center where solvers will not get any benefits/marks/gifts/advantages and internet and research have been allowed . This is not an exam .This is neither  contest nor mystery hunt . In the next class, teacher will solve them .

@@Gareth McCaughan before you decide anything , I have to give my closing argument.
